# VirtualBox options to resize window now showing

Tags: virtualbox

[image]

Now normally at the top there would be the following menu:

[image]

I seem to be missing the `Machine`, `View`, `Device` and `Help` drop downs.

Also the shortcuts `host key` + `*other key*` has no effect.

Comment: Obviously that is an issue of the Windows host - not much we can do from Ubuntu here.

Comment: @Takkat I made this happen(it was showing before) by selecting auto-resize in the View menu, so it feels like VB has something to do with it.

Comment: Just realized you have no tools bar too - it may be you are in "Scale Mode" - Try HOST+C for disabling it again (per dehault the HOST key is right CTRL).

Answer (score 1):

`Host+C` seemed to get it back to normal. Was in `Scale` mode without knowing it.

Comment: Was about to comment on that, not realizing you had found out yourself - Thanks for sharing :)